# Forwarding internal links: recommended redirect type

Tags: seo

We are setting up an internal banner system, and we want to track links clicked. So within our website, we link to

`http://example.com/forward/33`

Which in fact forwards to

`http://example.com/article/145`

But by passing the forward page, we can record some statistics. Now, for SEO purposes I would guess a 301 forward would be best (we'd be using a PHP header), so that search engines consider this in fact a link to the final internal page, and not the forwarder page. Is this the recommended approach? Is there a problem with having tons of 301 within your website? And is there anything else to be taken into account when forwarding internal links?

Answer (score 0):

301 redirect would be your best bet. However, with everything else I would use in moderation.